# cant create file on a server 'EPERM, operation not permitted' Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I'm an iOS developer but trying to write on node.js for for 3rd day;)

so I've got my resful api working and usind https://cloudno.de to host my server, and It seems like everthing is ok, but I have this line of code in my app:

```
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + '/cookies/' + username + '.json');
```

which is generating cookie file for a user, so its woking on my localhost (I'm using macOS) but on my server I've got this error :

```
fs.write = function(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback) {
                                             ^
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted '/app/2773-3c06b4e3bcc357fd4400a9b453bc4af5/cookies/komar_dima.json'
```

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.cloudno.de/cloud-storage.html) page you are allowed to create files on `/mnt` and `/tmp`.

So change path to that paths for creating cookie files.